# Python: I create 2 lists, I sort one of them and they both get sorted

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a list called self.nodePathList which contatins [782, 455, 231]. I then put it into another list variable: self.sortedNodePath = self.nodePathList. both lists now contain the same things. I sort self.sortedNodePath. Yet, they both get sorted. i checked through the code over and over but i'm not making any spelling errors or using the wrong names. the code is below if you want to use it

```
self.sortedNodePath = self.nodePathList

#######sorting

for passnum in range(len(self.sortedNodePath)-1,0,-1):
    for i in range(passnum):
           if self.sortedNodePath[i]>self.sortedNodePath[i+1]:
                  self.temp = self.sortedNodePath[i]
                  self.sortedNodePath[i] = self.sortedNodePath[i+1]
                  self.sortedNodePath[i+1] = self.temp

#######END OF SORTING
```

Comment: just ran this code without the "self." and with nothing else interfering. it's still sorting both lists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example, `self.sortedNodePath` and `self.nodePathList` both point to the same object.  When you sort that object, both variables are still pointing to it.

You need to create a new object by using:

```
self.sortedNodePath = list(self.nodePathList)
```

As an example:

```
foo = ['test', 'foo']
bar = foo

print id(foo)
>>> 23367192

print id(bar)
>>> 23367192   # You can see both foo and bar have the same object ID

bar = list(foo)

print id(bar)
>>> 23387392  # Now using list(), bar has a separate object ID from foo
```

Comment: See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list-in-python) for more information.  I never noticed it before but it appears as though using `list()` is a faster alternative.

Comment: The usual way to copy a list is `new = orig[:]`, since `list(orig)` can have unintended side effects if an object is sliceable but not ACTUALLY a list to begin with (e.g. a subclass of a list, or a string or etc)

Comment: Those unintended side effects would be a good thing, Python is meant to be very explicit, and creating a new ID using `list()` doesn't get any more explicit.  Slicing with `new = orig[:]` could for example be used to copy a tuple into a new tuple.  Which may not be intended.  If you are simply trying to copy a list then any errors received from `list()` should be considered a very useful and relevant hint from Python that you may need to reconsider what you are working with.

Answer (score 0):

You're not creating two lists, you're creating two references to the same list.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the ids of those two list objects with `print id(self.sortedNodePath)` and `print id(self.NodePathList)` you will see that they are both, in reality, the same list.

To make a real copy:

```
 self.sortedNodePath = []
 self.sortedNodePath.extend(self.nodePathList)
```

Also, note that in Python one usually sorts a list with `sorted(list)` or perhaps `list.sort()`.  If the items in your list are not simple types that Python knows how to compare, you can supply a function to both `sorted()` and `list.sort()` that will be used to extract a comparison value for each object in the list.